# Loading 2 Different Version of JS files

Tags: javascript

I am running a WP site with an old version (3.3.1) and much older theme. For some reasons i cannot update or change any of the code files.

The problem i am getting now is the theme is using local Jquery version 1.3.2 because of which some admin pages are responding weirdly.

The Jquery is hard-coded without any hook present so there is no way removing is without having to modify the core files (which i am not permitted to do).

I added an action hook on `admin_head` to load the required version of JS

```
function modify_jquery() {  
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'modify_jquery');
```

This is solving my problem and everything is working as expected.

My only question is will this (loading 2 JS files of different versions) create any problem in any other pages?

I checked some random pages but didnt find anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: how is this question specific to wordpress? side note: any single feature that still works on such an old code base is a small miracle, the only way to keep it working is by changing nothing, the only change that should be done is total overall.

Comment: .... and since browsers change, sometimes even changing nothing will not be good enough

Comment: Just want to know will using 2 different versions of Jquery cause any problem in WP core.

Comment: on a version that is obsolete for over 4 years? no one will know

Answer (score 1):

> My only question is will this (loading 2 JS files of different versions) create any problem in any other pages?

Likely. WP loads jQuery in `noConflict` mode, meaning it doesn’t occupy typical `$` variable, but only `jQuery` one. However another copy of jQuery can very well get in a fight over `jQuery` one with the core’s version.

Inherently this is possible, but requires very explicit implementation of `noConflict` so that two versions are kept separate and only called from code intended to use that specific version.

In a typical theme case it would probably be easier to fix up code to use current jQuery version properly, than bother implementing multi–version environment.